# way to have 3d animated/rigged character in Opengl

Tags: opengl

If I want a 3D animated/rigged character in OpenGL game how i would have it in OpenGL?If i make a animated/rigged character in 3Ds max is it possible to have that character in OpenGl?would be helpful if someone gives a proper way or a tutorial link to export animated model from 3d software to open GL

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read our [guide about how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and extend your question.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is a very simple 3D framework which only offers the bare bones. OpenGL can display triangles and fill them with color and that's about it. It comes with some helper functions to manipulate point clouds but it's really very basic.

Animation and rigging are way beyond what it can do. What you need is a framework which supports animation and rigging which then uses OpenGL to display the result.

Since you don't specify any requirements, it's hard to say which one would be good for you. [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is probably a good place to start. It's game engine runs on many platforms, supports OpenGL, animation and rigging.

Comment: Thanks for response I used to work in 3Ds Max....i want to know if i have had a rigged/animated character in 3Ds max how i will export it in Open GL??and once animatation done in 3ds max software how i will have it in Open gl??

Comment: You need a software like 3Ds Max that supports OpenGL. OpenGL alone can't do what you want.

Comment: I have 3Ds Max software and I devoloped a rigged 3D character but I want to have it in Open GL game with controls assigned to character...I m asking for a way to export my rigged Model to Open GL Game ?

Comment: As I already said in my answer: Export it into Blender. The Blender game engine can render on OpenGL.